# Ошибка в Unity UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow+BuildMethodException: 2 errors at UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow+DefaultBuildMethods.BuildPlayer

Tags: c#, unity3d, unity3d-android

Собираю подписанный апк на android вот что выдает:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: вы исправьте сначала ошибку в скрипте TreeUtils. Добейтесь того, что остались только не понятные вам ошибки, а после этого возможно и непонятные ошибки уйдут

Comment: и ошибки, которые у вас отображаются в консоли лучше скидывать текстом, на картинке их плохо видно или практически не видно

Comment: Так там нету ошибки В плеере все компилиться. Пространство имен using UnityEditorInternal в visual studio видит

Comment: то что его видит в VS не означеает что вы можете его в билде использовать. Unity вам и говорит, что не получится его использовать в билде. Это пространство имен доступно только в редакторе

Comment: Так а что мне с этим делать?

Comment: не использовать это пространство имен в билде) и все, что содержится в этом пространстве. Кроме этого еще и UnityEditor нельзя в билде использовать

Comment: Спс за ответы вроде скомпилировалось, пришлось удалить этот скрипт, который как оказалось ни на что не влиял.

Comment: вместо удаления можно еще обернуть весь скрипт в #if UNITY_EDITOR #endif

Comment: @vmchar, судя по всему, ваш диалог в комментариях привел к решению вопроса. Оформите, пожалуйста, теперь в виде ответа, что бы MadokaMagica смог закрыть вопрос.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ошибка, обозначенная в самом названии вопроса

> UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow+BuildMethodException: 2 errors at
>   UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow+DefaultBuildMethods.BuildPlayer

не является самостоятельной и говорящей, а означает то, что Unity не может собрать пакет для вашего приложения, из-за ошибок, возникших при компиляции вашего проекта. По этому, прежде, чем браться за решение этой не понятной ошибки, посмотрите в консоль Unity и исправьте более понятные ошибки.

Например в вашем случае присутствует ошибка :

> Assets/Marble Space/Scripts/UI/TreeViewUtils.cs(10,16): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'UnityEngineInternal' could not be found. Are you missing assembly reference?

Эта ошибка говорит о том, что в одном из скриптов у вас используется пространство имен `UnityEngineInternal`. Это пространство имен допустимо использовать в редакторе и Visual Studio или любая другая IDE не будут показывать ошибок, но его нельзя использовать в конечной сборке. Скорее всего, когда вы исправите эту ошибку остальные тоже исправятся, если нет других очевидных ошибок.